# SSIS steps executing before predecessor has completed

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that has just recently started running weirdly.

The image below illustrates what I am saying. A number of steps are being executed before there predecessor has completed.

[image: SSIS Package Example]

Answer (score 0):

This is normal.  What you're looking at isn't a control flow (do X, then do Y), but a data flow.

Data flows start working on the data that's come in before it's all come in.  So what you're seeing is *Derived Column* and *MOL CRM* starting to work on the data, before *Valid NPS Performance Data* has finished delivering all the data.

This, incidentally, is why certain operations (Sorts for example) are such a performance hit: they have to wait for all the data to be there before working.

Comment: 2 questions why is it just starting to do this for the last 2 weeks it has been running sequentially? And how did the error(column 2) log task start and complete before its source task?

Comment: to question 1: probably because there's now more data, enough for SSIS to decide to batch it into separate batches. So you see the first batch flowing through the Transformation items before the next batch comes through.  It's nothing to worry about, makes no logical difference to the outcome.

Comment: to question 2: the error log flow (it's not a task, but a dataflow), as designed on your diagram, is completely independent of the other flow on the left.  If you want to only start after the other data flow, you'll need to pull it out into a separate Data Flow task, and link them with an On Complete or On Success constraint.

Comment: Yes but how has the error log step completed before derived column 1 has started.

Comment: That I don't know, and can't see from the diagram.